# камера Basler аппаратный триггер

Tags: c#, камера, sdk

подключил к камере basaler аппаратный триггер (ардуино с кнопкой), он срабатывает, я получаю кадр, но проблема в том, что не могу его использовать повторно не перезагружая приложение.
вот код:

### Заголовок

```
if (camera.IsConnected){                       camera.Parameters[PLCamera.TriggerSource].SetValue(PLCamera.TriggerSource.Line1);
 
if (camera.Parameters[PLCamera.LineStatus].GetValue()) 
                    {
                        timer_trigger.Start();
                                             
                    }                            
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ShowException(exception);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Dispose the grab result if needed for returning it to the grab loop.
                e.DisposeGrabResultIfClone();
            }
 int second = 0;
        private void timer_trigger_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            try
            {
                second++;
                if (camera != null)
                {
                    camera.Parameters[PLCamera.LineSelector].SetValue(PLCamera.LineSelector.Line1);
                    camera.Parameters[PLCamera.TriggerActivation].SetValue(PLCamera.TriggerActivation.RisingEdge);
                    if (camera.Parameters[PLCamera.LineStatus].GetValue())
                    {

                        if (camera.Parameters[PLCamera.LineStatus].GetValue()&&second == 3)
                        {
                            trigger_btn.PerformClick();
                            MessageBox.Show("снимок сделан");
                            
                       }
                    }
                  
                }
                
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ShowException(ex);
            }
        }


private void trigger_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (pictureBox.Image != null) //если в pictureBox есть изображение
            {
                camera.StreamGrabber.Stop();
                //создание диалогового окна "Сохранить как..", для сохранения изображения
                SaveFileDialog savedialog = new SaveFileDialog();
                savedialog.Title = "Сохранить картинку как...";
                //отображать ли предупреждение, если пользователь указывает имя уже существующего файла
                savedialog.OverwritePrompt = true;
                //отображать ли предупреждение, если пользователь указывает несуществующий путь
                savedialog.CheckPathExists = true;
                //список форматов файла, отображаемый в поле "Тип файла"
                savedialog.Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP)|*.BMP|Image Files(*.JPG)|*.JPG|Image 
                  Files(*.GIF)|*.GIF|Image Files(*.PNG)|*.PNG|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                //отображается ли кнопка "Справка" в диалоговом окне
                savedialog.ShowHelp = true;
                if (savedialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //если в диалоговом окне нажата кнопка "ОК"
                {
                    try
                    {
                        pictureBox.Image.Save(savedialog.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

                    }

                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Невозможно сохранить изображение", "Ошибка",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }


                }

            }
        }
```